# New article page on Joomla fails

Tags: html, joomla

I have a problem which I have no clue how to solve. I have a joomla site which looks like working perfect (http://secretinvizimals.com/). There is only one page which fails - my add new article page.

Here is a link to my problem: http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/contribute
You might need to login first with these credentials: Username: StackOverflow password: StackOverflow
you can log in on the mainpage at the top: http://secretinvizimals.com/

Just very short: The problem is that the page comes out with no style:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of where I can start with this - or maybe a solution?

Here comes some faqs about my joomla site:

- Joomla version 2.5.7
- Custom theme developed in Artisteer 4.0

I hope you can help me.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools state that your missing the editor.css file. Which is the style sheet for editing stuff. The link its looking for it is here:
http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/skins/kama/editor.css?t=C3HA5RM
Although there is no file there - judging by the other links I'm guessing this was an old template or something?? You either need to change the file location if it does exist in another location or you need to create a file for it and put in the standard stuff.

Chrome developer tools is also finding half a dozen errors

```
<error> index.php:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/config.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/skins/kama/editor.css?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/lang/en-gb.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/plugins/linkBrowser/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/plugins/mediaembed/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/plugins/readmore/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/plugins/tableresize/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/plugins/autogrow/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "linkBrowser" was not found at "http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/../plugins/linkBrowser/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM". index.php:1519
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (x10)
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded index.php:1654 (x2)
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (x6)
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded index.php:1654 (x2)
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (x6)
```

The initial one being to do with the fact there is no doctype, html declaration or anything at the top of your page. Which is a bit more confusing. I'd have to assume that this was some kind of template issue. But obviously its a lot harder to test something like that from the outside access. Have you tried turning on the Joomla debug feature to see whats going on?

Comment: Thanks... I will try doing this

Comment: No worries. Let me know what you find out!

Comment: It still doesn't show right in internet explorer 10 and Chrome. But FireFox get it right. Do you know how that can be?

Comment: I can see you're merging together js files at the moment. Can you temporarily stop that please? Cause all the errors I'm seeing in the chrome console are "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in that merged javascript file. And would be useful to see if its something to do with the actual js or if its something to do with the way the files are combined! Firefox, chrome and IE all render differently so it's not uncommon for one to work and the others to break

Comment: got it to work. The error was exactly the merge of javascripts

Comment: Nice One! Glad you've got it going.